# Se cierra formulario en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Boton de abrir formulario:

```
 frmCatalogos formulario = new frmCatalogos();
        this.Hide();
        formulario.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
```

Todo bien hasta ahí.
El problema se ocaciona cuando doy Click a un boton en el siguiente formulario.
realiza todo el recorrido completo y luego retorna a `this.Show();` como puede quedar esto ya que si ven el funcionamiento pretendo solo crear una sola instancia de formulario.

Comment: y que hace el otro formulario?? y esto donde es que esta ubicado? falta bastante informacion como para poder ayudarte

Comment: En general tu pregunta no se entiende:  Podria explicar mejor, tienes 1 formulario con un boton que abre un formulario, esta muy redundante, podrias decir el F1 tiene boton que abre F2, en F2 tengo el boton siguietne que hace tal cosa... y etc., etc., pero si tu pregunta es: Como abro un formulario sin crear nuevas instancias? o Como hago para tener una sola instancia de F2 cada vez que le de click en el boton Siguiente... nose esque no se entiende en general.

Answer (score 5):

Para tener solo 1 instancia del formulario tendrias que hacer algo asi:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 formulario;//Declarar aqui la variable del formulario

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.formulario = new Form2();//Inicializarlo una sola vez

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        this.formulario.ShowDialog();//Llamarlo de este modo, sin poner el New
        this.Show();
    }

}
```

Comment: El problema fue que la propiedad **DialogResult** del botón estaba diferente de _none_

Comment: Ok... pero sigues poniendo información a medias, jejeje ntp de igual manera que bueno que lo resolviste.